# Display a textbox based on checkbox selected when checkbox list is dynamic using JSF

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have a requirement in my project which specifies to display 2 textboxes based on a checkbox is checked. For every check box selected the 2 textboxes are the same. The twist is the check box list is dynamic to accomodate additions in the future. The check box list comes from DB.
How can this be done in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueChangeListener property of  tag.

```
      <h:selectManyCheckbox id="" value="#{bean.selectedItems}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.renderTextBox}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{bean.checkBoxList}"/>
      </h:selectManyCheckbox>
<h:inputText value="" rendered="#{bean.render}"/>
```

Have property called render in your bean.
In valuechange method i.e renderTextBox write following code

```
public void renderTextBox(event)
{

 if(isInvokeApplicationPhase(event))
{
//change the value of render property to true or false depending on checkbox is checked or not
}

}
public boolean isInvokeApplicationPhase(FacesEvent event){      
    if(event.getPhaseId() != PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION){
        event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
        event.queue();
        return false;
    }       
    return true;
}
```

And to get checkbox list from database write following method

```
 public List getcheckBoxList() 
{
public List checkBoxList = null
// retrieve list of checkbox from your db(write query here and assign returned list to checkBoxList  variable and return that varaible)
}
```

getcheckBoxList()  is a getter method. I've bound checkBoxList variable to `<f:selectItems>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works :) But when I am adding two such checkbox lists which behave just the same. The FacecEvent is always getting set to true. And on unchecking the checkbox, the textbox must go away which is not happening. Tried to search more about this but no success yet.

Comment: If there is any checked checkbox in checkbox list textboxes will be displayed even though you unchecked one among them. That is what you wanted rite??

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to hide and display the input box

```
 var checkbox=document.getElementById("ID");

        if(checkbox.value== 'null')
            checkbox.style.display = "none";
        else
            checkbox.style.display = "inline";
```